# Postgres Query Plan keeps changing - takes a query a minute to finish sometimes and never finishes sometimes

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, sql-tuning

I have huge SQL Query. Probably 15-20 tables involved.
There are 6 to 7 subqueries which are joined again. 
This query most of times takes a minute to run and return 5 million records.

So even if this query is badly written, it does have query plan that makes it finish in a minute. I have ensured that query actually ran and didn't use cached results.

Sometimes, the query plan gets jacked up and then it never finishes. I run a vacuum analyze every night on the tables involved in the query. The work_memory is currently set at 200 MB..I have tried increasing this to 2 GB as well. I haven't experienced the query getting messed when work_memory was 2 GB. But when i reduced it and ran the query, it got messed. Now when i increased it back to 2 GB, the query is still messed. Has it got something to do with the query plan not getting refreshed with the new setting ? I tried discard plan on my session.

I can only think of work_mem and vacuum analyze at this point. Any other factors that can affect a smoothly running query that returns results in a minute to go and and not return anything ?

Let me know if you need more details on any settings ? or the query itself ? I can paste the plan too...But the query and the plan or too big to be pasting here..

Comment: 15-20 tables in range table: the genetic optimiser will kick in. Either increase geqo_limit, or put some of your table referencess into a CTE. If you already have some subqueries, promote one ore more of these to a CTE.

Comment: oops, the name is `geqo_threshold`.  its default value is 12. Setting it too high (20 is probably too high ...) will cause the planner to need **a lot of time** to evaluate all the plans. (the number of plans is basically exponential wrt the number of RTEs)

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than `geqo_treshold` (typically 12) entries in the range table, the genetic optimiser will kick in, often resulting in *random* behaviour, as described in the question. You can solve this by:

- increasing geqo_limit
- move some of your table referencess into a CTE. If you already have some subqueries, promote one (or more) of these to a CTE. It is a kind of black art to identify clusters of tables in your query that will fit in a *compact* CTE (with relatively few result tuples, and not too many key references to the outer query).

Setting geqo_treshold too high (20 is probably too high ...) will cause the planner to need a lot of time to evaluate all the plans. (the number of plans increases basically exponential wrt the number of RTEs) If you *expect* your query to need a few minutes to run, a few seconds of planning time will probably do no harm.

Comment: Did some reading on GEQO settings. I am pretty sure thats my issue here. My query is just too long and complex for a exhaustive search plan to be generated. That GECO based heuristic search is not yielding the best plan. I am going to slightly tweak the geqo_effort parameter and break repeated parts in my query into CTE's

Comment: But do you have a clue how each time my query plan gets messed , a vacuum analyze on the entire database fixes the issue. Is GEQO able to do a better plan after a vacuum analyze ?

Comment: It is just randomness & coincidence & heuristics, I don't want to know. Could be you have incremental keys, or even a miscalculation in the statistics... Once the geqo yields a cluster of related tables, variants using that cluster will probably prevail. (win the evolution). My advise: Just split off a (solid subquery) part of your query into a CTE.